# $scope.$on won't update UI

Tags: angularjs

in my angular service I do connect to my server via WebSocket and receive some real time updates. Via `$rootScope.$broadcast` I broadcast those updates to anyone who listens in the application.

```
        function handleTickerMessage(msg){
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(msg));
            $rootScope.$broadcast(config.events.ticker, msg);
        }
```

in a controller I'm subscribing to that event and update some local variables

```
    $scope.mainPair = {
        name: '',
        buy: 110.00,
        sell: 80.00
    };

    $scope.$on(config.events.ticker, function(event, ticker){
       if (config.mainPage.prodPair === ticker.prodPair){
           $scope.mainPair.name = config.mainPage.prodPair;
           $scope.mainPair.buy = parseFloat(ticker.bid);
           $scope.mainPair.sell = parseFloat(ticker.ask);
       }
    });
```

in the html file I try to display those new values

```
<span><i class="down"></i><em>{{mainPair.buy | currency}}</em></span>
```

but for some reason they are not displayed. I know for sure my `$on` is getting called and the `if` is working. So why the UI is not updated?

Funny think is, if I access a value from `mainPair` in a click event

```
    $scope.signUp = function (){
        console.log('buy: ' + $scope.mainPair_buy);
        return;
     }
```

then I do get the last value and UI is updated!!!

So why UI is not updated when the event comes?

thx

Comment: could you try with `$scope.$apply()` in your `$on`, just to be sure ?

Comment: try adding `$scope.$apply()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're calling `handleTickerMessage` from outside of angular.js framework, you have to wrap it in `$scope.$apply`.

For example, whatever WebSocket code you're using would have to do:

```
socket.on('someevent', function(msg){
   $rootScope.$apply(function(){
       handleTickerMessage.call(null, msg));
   });
});
```

Check out the documentation for [$rootScope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply):

**$apply([exp]);**
$apply() is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of the angular framework. (For example from browser DOM events, setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries). Because we are calling into the angular framework we need to perform proper scope life cycle of exception handling, executing watches.

Comment: thx, that helped! I wrote it like this             function onSocketMessage(e){
                var msg = JSON.parse(e.data);
                switch (msg.messageType){
                    case 'Ticker': $rootScope.$apply(function(){ handleTickerMessage(msg); }); break;
                }
            }

            function handleTickerMessage(msg){
                $rootScope.$broadcast(config.events.ticker, msg);
            }